# ORA-00969: missing ON keyword 00969. 00000 - "missing ON keyword"

Tags: plsql, database-trigger

I am getting 0099 error while creating below trigger:

```
create trigger AuditTrigger1  
before update, insert
on MPUZNTAB
for each row
declare
begin
insert into AuditTable1
(ZNCODE, DES , SHDES, WhenChanged)
values
(:new.ZNCODE,:new.DES,:new.SHDES, getdate())
end;
```

Please recomment changes

Comment: TRy `before update OR insert`.

Comment: There's no `getdate()` in Oracle, unless you have written your own function. According to Google it's from SQL Server.

Comment: You may find it helpful to look at some trigger sources [in the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#GUID-BD042B88-E2E7-4A7D-8FA2-8D0185F6455F__BCFDEHHE). You can resolve most of your syntax bloomers by comparing your code with those examples. On, and instead of `getdate()` you need to use `sysdate`;

Answer (score 1):

- You missed a semicolon at the end of the insert statement
- You should write before update OR insert
- If getdate() is not a user defined function, you should use SYSDATE instead, to get the current time
- I'm not sure the :new values are correct. Are they fields of the table MPUZNTAB?

This code should work:

```
Create Or Replace Trigger AuditTrigger1
  Before Update Or Insert On MPUZNTAB
  For Each Row
Declare
Begin
  Insert Into AuditTable1
    (ZNCODE,
     DES,
     SHDES,
     WhenChanged)
  Values
    (:new.ZNCODE,
     :new.DES,
     :new.SHDES,
     SYSDATE);
End;
```

Comment: That's just one of several syntax errors in the code. Can you find them all?

Comment: You're right. I just saw other replies on the question's comments, so I just added the missing one (I can't comment questions, so I created a fully answer). I edited the answer, that should do it